# Storing UUID() vs UUID().uuidString using Realm

Tags: swift, realm, uuid

I have an object that needs to be stored using Realm, for simplicity's sake, like this:

```
class ExampleObject: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    ...
}
```

Is it better to store the `id` as a `String`, or should I be using `UUID` instead?

```
@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: UUID = UUID()
```

Also, is there any way to cluster the generation of UUIDs in Swift?

Comment: I would store the id as String instead. var id = UUID().uuidString. Because Realm does not really provide a full support for the unique key of Swift from my experience.

Comment: I agree with @Carrot. I would suggest looking at a Realm specific object that works really well for primaryKey's called [ObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Classes/ObjectId.html). There's a little write up about using [ObjectId](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/data-types/supported-property-types/#unique-identifiers). It's a great object for that purpose and when implemented `@Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId` it only auto-generates when needed and works great with Sync. Oh, and what do you mean by `cluster the generation of UUIDs in Swift?`

Comment: Thank you! By `cluster generation` I meant if there's a way to generate sequential or near-sequential UUIDs, and if that's advisable at all?

Comment: Yes, that can be done and using ObjectId's (as suggested by Realm) for your keys will provide somewhat of an order to the data. HOWEVER, you are way better off defining how you want ordering via a field; timestamp, date or some other known property.